# Retrieving a List of Subcategory under a major Category and passing it to the View

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

good evening all. first am working on an e-learning project. to the problem.

i have a `Course`Class that has `IEnumerable<Modules>` and a `Module` class that has `IEnumerable<Topics>`. Currently when a user clicks on any of the courses on the view it opens up a `CourseDetail` View. This view is intended to show the details of the `Course` to the user.Like all the modules and when a module is clicked I want a drop down of all Topics under each Module.

This is where i am finding it really difficult. I Could retrieve all the `Modules` for the course but i am finding it difficult bringing `ToList()` all the topics for each module. So that when a user clicks on a Module it opens an inner div that lists all the topics.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CourseDetail(int id)
        {
            var course = _context.Courses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CourseId == id);
            var courseId = course.CourseId;

            var video = _context.Topic.Include(m => m.Modules).Where(m => m.Modules.CourseId == courseId).Sum(m => m.Duration);


            float totalSeconds = video;
            TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds);
            var duration = time.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss"); // 00:03:48
            var moduleCount = _context.Modules.Where(c => c.CourseId == courseId).Count();


           var courseModules = await _context.Modules.Where(c => c.CourseId == courseId).ToListAsync();
            foreach (var module in courseModules)
            {
                var moduleId = module.ModuleId;
                var moduleTopics = _context.Topic.Where(c => c.ModuleId == moduleId).ToList();
                ViewBag.moduleTopics = moduleTopics;
            }





            return View(course);
        }
```

This is what I have done. and my view Looks like this

```
 <div id="accordion_lessons" role="tablist" class="add_bottom_45">
                        @foreach (var module in ViewBag.Modules)
                        {
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne_@module.ModuleId">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne_@module.ModuleId" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"><i class="indicator ti-minus"></i>@Html.Raw(module.Title)</a>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>

                                <div id="collapseOne_@module.ModuleId" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion_lessons">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="list_lessons">
                                            <ul>
                                                @foreach (var topic in ViewBag.moduleTopics)
                                                {
                                                    <li><a href="#" class="video">@topic.Title</a><span>@topic.Duration</span></li>
                                                }

                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }


                    </div>
```

I realized that the `Viewbag.ModuleTopics` only holds the topic list for the last item ie `Module` which i am looping through via the `foreach` statement please how possible can i achieve Listing out Course Modules and on click of any module it shows an inner div that lists out the topics . thanks

Comment: Why dont you add your properties to a model and use it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

You can store a list of all topics in ViewBag and use it in your view to display topics for each course.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CourseDetail(int id)
        {
            var course = _context.Courses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CourseId == id);
            var courseId = course.CourseId;

            var video = _context.Topic.Include(m => m.Modules).Where(m => m.Modules.CourseId == courseId).Sum(m => m.Duration);


            float totalSeconds = video;
            TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds);
            var duration = time.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss"); // 00:03:48
            var moduleCount = _context.Modules.Where(c => c.CourseId == courseId).Count();


           ViewBag.Topics= _context.Topic.ToList();

           return View(course);
        }
```

And in the view..

```
<div id="accordion_lessons" role="tablist" class="add_bottom_45">
@foreach(var module in ViewBag.Modules)
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne_@module.ModuleId">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne_@module.ModuleId" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"><i class="indicator ti-minus"></i>@Html.Raw(module.Title)</a>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne_@module.ModuleId" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion_lessons">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="list_lessons">
                        <ul>
                            @var topicsForCurrentModule = ViewBag.Topics.Where(c => c.ModuleId == module.ModuleId)
                            @foreach (var topic in topicsForCurrentModule)
                                                {
                                <li><a href="#" class="video">@topic.Title</a><span>@topic.Duration</span></li>
                            }

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```